# Bracket fungus on apple tree

Tags: trees, plant-health, diseases

This bracket fungus is growing on an apple tree in my garden. I noticed one growing in the same position last year and just knocked it off. The tree is otherwise in pretty good condition. Should I try to remove it with a fungicide or just leave it be?

[image: bracket fungus]

Comment: That's only the "fruiting part" of the fungus. Most of the fungus is in the tree, meaning there's an area of rot (not terribly uncommon on old apple trees.)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a close watch on the tree if its in danger of falling on people or buildings when it falls, because it will, at some point. Bracket fungus like this on a tree trunk spells death I'm afraid, so its just a matter of time till it dies. As Ecnerwal says in the comment, this is just the fruiting body of fungal mycelium which have invaded the tree, and it will be progressing throughout the tree over time, destroying the wood as it goes. There is no treatment I'm afraid.